# OpenGL ES: Texture a plane

Tags: android, opengl-es, entity, textures, plane

I've gotten the texture to load, but it seemingly displays a single color of the texture. I've targeted the texture coordinates first, and can't seem to get the texture to display right. the intended texture is below:

[image: Test image for plane.]

256x256

The texture is being displayed, but seemingly in a solid color. Maybe zoomed in to one pixel of the texture, or a warp of bad texture coordinates.:

[image: Texture display.]

Geometry:

```
static float squareCoords[] = {     
        -0.1f,  0.1f, 0.0f,  
        -0.1f, -0.1f, 0.0f,   
        0.1f, -0.1f, 0.0f,    
        0.1f,  0.1f, 0.0f };
```

Texture coordinates:

```
final float TextureCoordinates[]  =
    {
            0.0f, 0.0f,
            0.0f, 1.0f,
            1.0f, 1.0f,
            1.0f, 0.0f,
    };
```

The texturing process is encapsulated inside the Entity class and I could include more code if it isn't immediately obvious to a second pair of eyes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On an unforeseeable note, `GLES20.glEnableVertexAttribArray(mTextureUniformHandle);` was not set.